# How to restrict Collection.find() to certain select patterns in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am experimenting with a simple chat app and Meteor 0.8.0

For a list of messages, where each message references a user through `user_id`, I want to display the username together with the message.

Is it possible to restrict the select patterns for a find()-call, so that e.g. `Meteor.users.find({_id: msg.userId})` is allowed but not `Meteor.users.find({})`?

Unfortunately this is not covered by Collection.allow/.deny, where I think would be the natural place. If this would be possible, I could simply use `Meteor.publish("usersWithName",function() {Meteor.users.find({},{fields:{username:1}});` without having to worry that the complete user list can be fetched on the client by an attacker.

Currently, I am using the `smart-publish` package to publish only the users referenced by messages, but I would prefer a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to restrict find queries from being run client-side, since the server is never contacted. It just runs the query against it's local collection. In the same way that an insert, update, or delete first happens client-side and then validates against the server (i.e. someone can remove a document on their client but the server will then reject it).

The best way to handle this is to only publish the documents you specifically need. As you mentioned, if you only publish the documents that the client should have then you are secure. Even if there was a way to force a restriction on the search client-side, it still does not really make sense to pass down more collections than you need.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I guess, what I am really missing in Meteor is a simple way to define (named) views. Publish/subscribe is ok, but not powerful enough.